# Why do I not have permission to extract any archives?

Tags: 11.10, ntfs, archive

I don't know what happened but all my archives have turned to read only mode.  I can't extract my archives any more:

[image: extract not working]

This is an issue only on NTFS partitions, not home

[image]
[image]
(The same archive could be extracted in my home folder)
[image]

Also the "extract here" context menu option is missing:

[image: context menu]

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your NTFS partitions are mounted read-only.  This sometimes happens if the filesystem was not unmounted cleanly.

To check this, open a terminal and type:

```
mount
```

Look for the NTFS partitions and see if they are mounted "ro" or "rw".  "ro" indicates that they are read-only.

You can try remounting them rw:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw [filesystem]
```

where "[filesystem]" is the NTFS filesystem in question.

It's likely that they will still not remount as read/write if they were improperly unmounted and are unchecked.  In that case, you should reboot your system into Windows and run the disk checker from there.  After that your partitions will be marked as clean and able to be mounted read/write again.

Comment: here is an image to that command http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/7610/narutonarutoinspironn51.png

Comment: @Naruto, that definitely shows that your NTFS partition is mounted read-only.  You could try "sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda9" to see if that does the trick, but I strongly suspect it will fail.  If it does fail, you'll need to run checkdisk/scandisk on that drive from a Windows system.  Ubuntu will not write to it as it could cause corruption if the filesystem is in an inconsistent state.